# Vue mounted() not detecting the innerWidth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a **Nuxt** page where I need to detect if the page is opened in mobile or desktop. I have tried to use the `window.innerWidth` property for the detection, but it seems it is not working when putting it in the `mounted()` lifecycle hook.

Below is the code:

```
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      isMobile: false,
      ...
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
    console.log(this.isMobile); // logs `false`
  },
```

But is I put the statement inside `created()` lifecycle it is again throwing error as `window is not defined`.

**My doubt is why is that? `created()` runs before then `mounted()` and also, my ESLint is showing error like "no-globals-in-created"**.

Please help here!

Comment: Its in the docs, vue lifecycle -> mounted + tick has rendered dom, use `await vm.$nextTick()`

Comment: I tried to reproduce, take a look at my example, it looks like it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also wrap your content in a div, and use the ref tag to access the initial clientWidth of the page, something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    size: null,
  },
  computed: {
    deviceType() {
        return this.size > 760 ? 'Desktop' : 'Mobile'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.size = this.$refs.pageSizeContainer.clientWidth
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{this.size}}px
  <div ref="pageSizeContainer" style="background: #f5f5f5;padding:15px">
    Device size is a {{this.deviceType}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it required to define the `isMobile` value in the mounted hook? If no I would suggest that you create a computed property `isMobile` that returns true/false based on the `innerWidth`

```
computed: {
    isMobile() {
        return window.innerWidth < 768;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are opening this on a desktop if you can open chrome's console so if this is the case, the problem here is that you did not setup a resize event listener along with the initial code in the mounted hook.

Something like this should work in your case:

```
this.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
console.log(this.isMobile);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  this.isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
  console.log(this.isMobile); // Should log true once width point is reached.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the `window.innerWidth` in the mounted hook works just as expected. And your code should work as well. Try logging the `window.innerWidth` value as well to see what's going on.

I created a quick sandbox where you can check it. The page loads, reads `window.innerWidth` and sets `isMobile` accordingly.
https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-tree-bgwo3

However, it only works during load of the page. It does not reevaluate when the window is resized. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: window.innerWidth logs as 1315 value. I don't know how?

anyways, @procoib's answer solved the issue